# Area under the curves $1/x$ and $1/x^2$

Tags: integration

Area under $1/x$ curve is considered to be infinite. Area under $1/x^2$ curve is considered to be finite. Why is it so?

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about bounds of $x=1$ and $x =\infty$, right?

Comment: From x=1 to x=∞, yes.

Comment: The both areas are infinite (if you start from zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are referring to the fact that

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx = 1$$

whilst

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx = \infty$$

This is the way that "area under a curve" is normally defined. These integrals follow from calculus, for example

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx = \left[ -\frac{1}{x} \right]_1^\infty = 0 - (-1) = 1$$

and

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx = \left[ \log x\right]_1^\infty = \infty$$

since log x is unbounded as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I guess you meant lnx not logx.

Comment: @DavidHoffman When mathematicians write $\log x$ they generally mean the natural logarithm. If they want the logarithm in some other base, say base 10, they will write $\log_{10} x$.

Answer (score 4):

By the definition of area itself. What is the area of an unbounded region of the plane? It is usually defined by an improper integral, as in your case: the areas are
$$
\lim_{b \to +\infty} \int_1^b \frac{dx}{x} = +\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{b \to +\infty} \int_1^b \frac{dx}{x^2} < +\infty.
$$

It is a matter of definitions, rather than of intuition. We can say that first comes the integral, then comes the area.

Comment: That seems to be like a reasonable justification, thank you.

Comment: @DavidHoffman: Even without mentioning an integral, it is not hard to argue that the area is infinite. If you are familiar with the standard argument that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots$ diverges, it is basically the same.