# What makes one integral converge and a similar integral diverge, e.g., $\int\limits_1^\infty\frac1x dx$ vs $\int\limits_1^\infty \frac1{x^2}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, area

The area under $\dfrac 1x$ curve within $[1, \infty)$ is considered to be infinite but for $\dfrac 1{x^2}$ curve, it is $1$.

Can someone please explain this to me intuitively?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Area under the curves $1/x$ and $1/x^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193629/area-under-the-curves-1-x-and-1-x2)

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I agree that this question is the same as in the duplicate post but the answers in those posts state what is already known: one integral converges and the other does not. I believe what is being asked for is an intuitive explanation of why one should converge and not the other. Why should the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ be unbounded while the integral of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not?

Comment: Ummm... the curves are different, so their areas are different.  What more would you like?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It seems like the asker wants to understand intuitively why one diverges and the other does not. We can take the area from 1 to infinity of $x^{-2}$ and $x^{-3}$ which both converge, unlike the question, but are different curves.

Comment: @JohnDouma Are you seriously asking why one converges while the other doesn't? Why does $L_{x\to \infty} x = \infty$ but $L_{x\to \infty} 1/x = 0$? Two different functions, we go by what the definition tells us.

Comment: $1/x^2$ obviously approaches $0$ a lot fast than $1/x$ as $x\to+\infty. \qquad$

Comment: I think the most intuitive explanation is that the anti-derivative of $x^n$ is $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, for $n\neq -1$. When $n=-1$, this formula "breaks" and we get $\ln(x)$ instead. For $n$ even slightly smaller than $-1$, $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ goes to $0$ as $x\to \infty$, whereas $\ln(x)$ does not.

Comment: To have finite area, the curve needs to bend toward the axes fast enough that the area is thin enough to be finite.

Comment: Why does $\ln x \to \infty$ but ${1 \over x} \to 0$?

Comment: Some intuition: if $x=100$ then $1/x =1/100$ but $1/x^2 = 1/10000$

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I am not asking anything. I am suggesting that marking this as duplicate is a misreading of the question. The asker appears to know that one converges and the other doesn't. The question demands an intuitive answer, not the evaluation of an integral.

Comment: Intuition comes from practice. One thing is "big", and the other "small", and it doesn't matter if they look like brothers.

Answer (score 2):

As many have pointed out in the comments, $\frac{1}{x^2}$ gets smaller a lot faster than $\frac{1}{x}$. As $x$ gets large the comparison between the two fractions is astronomical.

Consider $x=10^{12}$ (a trillion). $\frac{1}{x}$ is one trillionth but $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is a trillionth of that. What does that difference look like? Suppose you are standing at $x=10^{12}$ and the curve $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ looks like it is one foot above you. Then The curve $y=\frac{1}{x}$ appears to be a trillion feet above you.

A trillion feet is about $189$ million miles which about twice the distance as the sun is from the earth. Can you see how the two curves are really not that similar in the way they tail off?

Comment: I don't really think the "a lot faster" argument is very intuitive. It doesn't explain why the integral of $1/x^{1.00001}$ converges while $1/x$ doesn't.

Comment: @AmejiB. The argument is the same for $\frac{1}{x^{1.0001}}$ because we get $\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{x^{.001}}$ . Just as in the above case we get a coefficient that causes our function's value to be insignificant compared to $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: It shows why one is smaller than the other, but not why one is infinite (and thus larger than any real number), and the other is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Although "intuition" varies from person to person, it would be accurate to note that $\int_1^\infty {1\over x^p}dx$ is (by the fundamental theorem of calculus) easily verified to converge for $p>1$, and to diverge for $p\le 1$.

For me, the "intuition" about this comes entirely from that computation. I have no genuine physical intuition for those infinite integrals. But I know the fundamental theorem of calculus, and can do the pursuant easy algebra, so I know what is true.

And I've known what is true for many decades, so it is "part of my intuition".

I seriously think that is possibly the most accurate-and-honest answer you can get on this.

Comment: Intuition should be different from computation.

Comment: @Starlight ... doesn't computation "inform" intuition? And surely intuition, once informed, changes? I guess different people attribute different senses to "intuition" and "computation", etc. :)

Comment: Visual understanding helps complement algebra skills. For example, the distance from the x axis for a graph.